# Is there a concurrency problem with java's run method

Tags: java, concurrency

In my opinion, run method in Thread is invoked by jvm, is there a concurrency problem? when I read FutureTask's source code, I found it use CAS to set current thread. Why can't use:
`runner = Thread.currentThread()`

```
public void run() {
    if (state != NEW ||
        !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                     null, Thread.currentThread()))
        return;
    try {
        Callable<V> c = callable;
        if (c != null && state == NEW) {
            V result;
            boolean ran;
            try {
                result = c.call();
                ran = true;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                ran = false;
                setException(ex);
            }
            if (ran)
                set(result);
        }
    }
```

Also, why don't use `if (state != NEW && !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,null, Thread.currentThread()))` so that run method can only be execute once,then            `set(result)` can replace to

```
protected void set(V v) {
        outcome = v;
        UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, NORMAL); // final state
        finishCompletion();
    }
}
```

not

```
protected void set(V v) {
    if (UNSAFE.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, NEW, COMPLETING)) {
        outcome = v;
        UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, NORMAL); // final state
        finishCompletion();
    }
}
```

Is there necessary to use CAS？

when I use `Future<Integer> futureTask1 = executor.submit(callable)`,submit method will `RunnableFuture<T> ftask = newTaskFor(task)`. If I use

```
FutureTask futureTask = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            return null;
        }
    })
    new Thread(futureTask);
    new Thread(futureTask);
```

this is useless. So in diffrent threads there are diffrent RunnableFuture Object，therefore, there is no need for guarantee concurrent calls to run(), Could someone tell me what I miss,thanks

Developers who are new to the workplace are trying hard to learn multithreading knowledge, thank you for your answers

Comment: It's a `Runnable`, right? Can be passed to two threads, and both of them can be started. You probably don't want this.

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn Thanks，your answer helps me a lot

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I trying to figure out why use CAS at run method